# On html how to you increase var by one and save it

Tags: html

I have taken Web Design, but I never learned how to take a variable on a website and each time  someone clicks on it to increase by one and save it so the next user will see var+1.

For example how facebook liking works

Comment: Use asynchronous javascript and store the value in a database or some other form of persistent memory.

Comment: Hi Chris. Welcome to web development. Most of the answer here seem to ignore your level of knowledge and throw thing at you like asynchronous javascript, JavaScript, POST, AJAX etc. Though these aren't wrong answer it seem that you aren't advanced enough to understand these. 

I suggest you learn html+php by following tutorial. I personaly like the ones from 'thenewboston' http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=11

This should provide you a good and sound base before you tackle problems like these. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a simple task done by HTML only.

You'll need a database to store the number of likes. Other technologies like PHP and Ajax should also be used. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575049/how-to-create-a-facebook-style-like-system) gives you a little explanation on how to implement such a system.

Comment: Thanks I think this is a little over my head. Do web builders like godaddy or wordpress have this feature in them?

Comment: GoDaddy is a hosting service and Wordpress is a Content Management System. That's two different things. But yes, you can use these technologies with them

Answer (score 1):

You need a database in the server, and use JavaScript to  POST an Ajax query to server, and on page request you'd need a server side scripting language (e.g. PHP) to query the database for the value of the variable and generate a HTML page with that value. It's not possible to do it with pure HTML.